# SQLSyntaxErrorException Using LTRIM to trim character 'x' in query

Tags: sql, hibernate, db2, mockito, relational-database

I using TRIM function to trim some characters in query, I using hibernate following is my query.

```
from ABean s where s.cId in (select ca.id from CBean ca where LTRIM(ca.refNumber,'0') = LTRIM('$ref$','0') and ca.valid = 0)
```

**$ref$ is replace with actual value in query.**

I am seeing a different behaviour when I am running with DB2 and When I am running with Mockito test (Using In memory DB).
With DB2 this query is working fine but with Mockito in memory db I am getting `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException`, Error is something like this.

```
Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 1, column {column_number_in_actual_query}.
```

I am not able to make it working with in memory db, Is there anything wrong I am doing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in IBM DB2, in the SYSIMB schema, LTRIM takes a second argument of characters being trimmed like you have ([see here](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002412.html?pos=2)). However, in the SYSFUN schema (and in most other SQL implementations) it only takes one argument and assumes you are trimming whitespace ([see here](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000825.html?pos=2)).

Based on the error it looks like the interpreter wasn't expecting a comma, so it's probably trying to use the more standard version of the function and failing when it sees the second argument.

based on the [documentation for function references](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0009029.html) you should be able to replace LTRIM with SYSIBM.LTRIM

Comment: replaced with SYSIBM.LTRIM but now getting `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "LTRIM" at line 1, column {some column index}`